# Java using static void inside static int in same class

Tags: java, static, int, increment

```
public class A {
    private static int B = 0;

    public static void C() {
        //write your code here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

How can I increment `B` inside the `public static void C()`?

Comment: Just do `B++;` inside the method `C`.

Comment: Trying out `B = B + 1` is no option for you? Would be much faster than opening a thread here...

Comment: Jesper you should have just made an answer

Comment: also the question title doesn't match the actual question.  The int would be inside the class.  Probably the real question is "how do I call c to increment b"

Answer (score 1):

Using the Increment Operator is the easiest solution,

```
B++;
```

Or you can do it manually,

```
B = B + 1;
```

---

Read more,

- [Java - Increment Decrement Operators](https://www.dyclassroom.com/java/java-increment-decrement-operators)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

 class A { 
private static int B = 0;

public static void C() {
    B++;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    C();
    System.out.println(B);

}
}
```

Although the variable 'B' is private, it is external variable and is accessible in all the methods of that class, it won't be accessible from outside of the class. so, you can increment it without any problem inside the class